# How to convert the SQL query to ElasticSearch style?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, yii2

I have this complex query for **MySQL** which counts unique visits for each day. I want to make it faster using **ElasticSearch**.

Imagine a **table** like this:

- id | site_id | created_at ________ | stat_cookie_hash
- 10 | 12346 | 2019-11-11 15:42:24 | sf2f2eghasdh2nvr
- 11 | 12346 | 2019-10-26 09:41:09 | jk67j97jkhjghklj
- 12 | 12346 | 2019-10-26 14:25:01 | vnuoi96iyoui60yu
- 13 | 12346 | 2019-09-01 18:12:54 | zxcqscgscv1vcdcv

**Result** of the query would be like:

- 2019-11-11 | 1
- 2019-10-26 | 2
- 2019-09-01 | 1

The **SQL** query itself:

```sql
    SELECT day, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT stat_cookie_hash, DATE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL :timezone MINUTE)) as day
        FROM stat_visitor
        WHERE site_id=:site_id) AS T
    GROUP BY day
    ORDER BY day DESC
```

:timezone is an integer like 180

:site_id is an integer like 40

**The same one but with substitution:**

```sql
    SELECT day, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT stat_cookie_hash, DATE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 180 MINUTE)) as day
        FROM stat_visitor
        WHERE site_id=40) AS T
    GROUP BY day
    ORDER BY day DESC
```

ElasticSearch version:

```
{
    "version" : {
        "number" : "7.4.1",
        "build_flavor" : "default",
        "build_type" : "rpm",
        "build_hash" : "fc0eeb6e2c25915d63d871d344e3d0b45ea0ea1e",
        "build_date" : "2019-10-22T17:16:35.176724Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "8.2.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
      }
}
```

I'm completely new to ElasticSearch, so I don't know how to manage it. Help me, please!

It would be great if you know Yii2 Framework and could show me how to rewrite the SQL query with yii2-elasticsearch extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a soultion.

First of all, I removed timezone and DATE, DATE_ADD functions from the query.

Then I converted it to ElasticSearch format. It's integrated PHP version:

```
    public static function elasticSearch($site_id, $page_id=null, $markup_id=null, $started_at=null, $group_by='created_day')
    {
        $index = 'stat_visitor';

        $client = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setSelector('\Elasticsearch\ConnectionPool\Selectors\RoundRobinSelector')
            ->build();

        $params = [
            'index' => $index,
            'size' => 0,
            'body' => [
                'aggs' => [
                    'cnt' => [
                        'terms' => [
                            'field' => $group_by,
                            'size' => 9999,
                            'order' => ['_term' => 'desc'],
                        ],
                        'aggs' => [
                            'unique_hashes' => [
                                'cardinality' => [
                                    'field' => 'stat_cookie_hash'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['term' => ['site_id' => $site_id]],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'sort' => ['created_day' => 'desc'],
            ]
        ];

        if ($page_id) {
            $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = ['term' => ['page_id' => $page_id]];
        }

        if ($markup_id) {
            $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = ['term' => ['markup_id' => $markup_id]];
        }

        if ($started_at) {
            $params['body']['query']['bool']['filter'][] = ['range' => ['created_at' => [ 'gte' => $started_at]]];
        }

        $response = $client->search($params);

        $result = [];
        foreach ($response['aggregations']['cnt']['buckets'] as $bucket) {
            $result[$bucket['key_as_string']] = $bucket['unique_hashes']['value'];
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Yii2 elasticsearch guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-ar.md) would help you.

But in my opinion it won't help you in speeding up. You can use memcache and cache sql result.

I suggest you to store visit count in cache and update sql periodically.

Consider that elasticsearch doesn't have 'GROUP BY'

Comment: Yes, I've read this guide, but I still have no idea how to write this query.
Yes, I use Redis as cache now, and it's not enough.